# D3 Chart performance drops when animating 30k+ datapoints

Tags: javascript, reactjs, performance, animation, d3.js

https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/misty-violet-kxcl29

I have build a chart in d3 and react where I try to simulate a data stream by adding new datapoints on every frame.

The animation starts pretty smooth, but as the dataset keeps increasing, the FPS drop significantly - see the FPS counter at the top.

Is this to be expected? Is my implementation shitty? Can this be optimised?

Any advice is greatly appreciated.